# Using matlab to measure probability of picking coloured cards

Tags: matlab, probability

Okay so I want to use matlab to generate 40 cards, each 10 is a different colour, Red, Blue, Green and purple or whichever you want. Each time you pick a card it's removed and I've worked out the probability on paper to be

```
1 x 30/39 x 20/38 x 10/37 
10.94%
```

1 because you'll definitely pick a card the first time, then you have a 30/39 chance of picking a different colour, then 20/38 to pick the final 2 colours then a 10/37 chance of picking the last colour.

I want to know how someone would simulate this in matlab. I thought you could generate an 4x10 matrix of random numbers between 1 and 40 then check each row and for each number change it to it's corresponding colours letter so the numbers between 1-10 change to R, 11-20 to Blue and etc.

Then look at each of the rows and if the row contains R B G P ( in any order ) then a counter steps. Then take the amount from the counter and divide it by the total number of rows and it should come out to about 10% and then closer if you tried 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000 etc.

But I don't know how to do iteration through to change the numbers to letters or check to see what it contains. Does anyone have any ideas or a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html) (from the Statistics Toolbox) to sample without replacement:

```
I = 1e5; %// how many samples to take
successes = 0; %// this will contain how many samples are successful
for ii = 1:I
  sample = randsample(40,4); %// sample without replacement
  successes = successes + all(sort(ceil(sample/10)) == (1:4).'); %'// a sample is
  %// successful if it contains all four colours. 1st colour = cards 1 to 10;
  %// 2nd colour = cards 11 to 20, etc.
end
estimate = successes/I %// estimate of success probability
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! Can you explain what the success(ii) = all(sorts(ceil(sample/10)) == (1:4).') does in more detail please?

Comment: Assume the sample is "successful". That means there is one card in the set 1--10 (colour 1), another in set 11--20 (colour 2) etc. Then `ceil(( )/10)` applied to those four successful cards will give 1, 2, 3, 4, not  necessarily in that order. So apply `sort` (i.e. sort the card sample using colour order) and then test if first card is colour 1 and second card is colour 2 and so on (that's the `all` part).

Comment: Woah. That's clever. I like that a lot! Thank you so much!